# ¿Al rotar pantalla se pierden las instancias de los controles?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Por curioso que parezca no he tenido problemas con rotar la pantalla y los controles, hasta ahora, que tengo mis controles, hasta que llegaron los `Fragment` tengo ese dichoso problema al rotar el dispositivo pierde la instancia de los controles:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference

Método que controla los datos:

```
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    MF_F_Datos mff_data = (MF_F_Datos) adapter.getItem(0);
    MF_F_Galeria mff_galeria = (MF_F_Galeria) adapter.getItem(1);

    mff_data.ActMuestraDatos(_id_mf_l, mod);
```

Mientras no rote la pantalla el *app* trabaja bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar en tu Activity:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".myActivity"         
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

con esto no destruiría la Activity ni el Fragmento que lo contiene pero este tipo de error que comentas :

> ¿Al rotar pantalla se pierden las instancias de los controles?

es posiblemente que se pierden las referencias, esto puede ser porque tienes un Layout diferente definido para otra orientación.

Comment: ok deja probar, pero manejo dimens,

Comment: @MarkDias que layout carga y ya verificaste si tienes otro layout para otra orientacion?

Comment: solo manejo un layout, pero si diferentes dimens, ya se arreglo usos pequeños detalles que te erizan el alma, muchas gracias @Elanasys, que haria sin usted gracias totales

Comment: Que bien Mark pero solucionaste este problema, cual era el problema de no encontrar la referencia al rotar?

Comment: si se perdian las referencias o instacia a los controles, muchas gracias por cierto hablando de otro tema has trabajado con el FingerPrintManagar para obtener el mapeo o escaneo de una huella???

Comment: @MarkDev sinceramente no he trabajado con : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html veo es parte del SDK muy interesante :|

Comment: Si es muy interesante y las aplicaciones son uffff si ya me leí el documento